# To apply: "send your resume with salary requirement" Thats it? Nothing else?

Tags: resume, human-resources, applications

Employer's website states:

> If you are interested in a career opportunity with __: mail, fax or
>   email your resume with salary requirement to: __

Do I literally just send the 1 page resume with salary requirement (if I decide to include it)? Or do I need to write them a letter or something too?

Do I need to explain myself / thank them?

Comment: What industry (retail, service, IT, etc) and what level of job (entry, junior, mid, senior)? Sometimes a cover letter isn't really needed. It might be enough to write a short paragraph in the email to say "please consider..." and "...thank you"

Comment: @HorusKol: ... and what country?

Comment: hehe   Salary req:  One doubloon every week.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... Factory Automation. Mid level job. USA.

Answer (score 12):

> Do I literally just send the 1 page resume with salary requirement (if
>   I decide to include it)? Or do I need to write them a letter or
>   something too?

Send your resume. And send a cover letter stating your salary requirement.

As always, the cover letter should mention the job you are applying for, why you would be a good fit, and should convey your excitement about the possibility of working for the company.

As @Lilienthal correctly points out, when there isn't a specific job posting, your cover letter would instead talk about the kind of profile you have and how your skills and experience would be valuable for the company

Basically, the employer's website is indicating that they want to be sure you include both your resume and salary requirement. They aren't saying that's all you are allowed to send.

And if you decide not to include your salary requirement, they will almost certainly reject your application.

Comment: For the max salary possible angle, you might want to set your salary request a bit higher than what you think is fair, but not too much. That way there's some room to negotiate.

Comment: +1 for the note that if you don't include your salary they will probably reject your application. BUT it might help if you proactively use linkedin (or call the company) to reach out to recruitment to discuss the role, explain your CV and then discuss the salary requirement. Maybe they are as firm (as I suspect they might be) as Joe suggests, maybe not.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere well, suppose the average salary for the position is 100k a year, and you want to ooze out as much as you can (as you should), you might add about 10 - 15 % extra on top of that. But if you go for say 25 - 30 % more, it's probably too much unless you are truly exceptional *and can prove it*. But even if you are a top 5%, you still risk being skipped outright if your request is 50 % more than average.

Comment: +1 to Joe but consider, if salary expectations are as high (or higher) than your skills when selecting who to interview, is it really somewhere that values employees appropriately?  It would be a red flag for me.

Answer (score 2):

If that is what they requested, that is all you need.

An appropriate cover letter won't do any harm, but may or may not help depending on how their process works.

Comment: This is a good point, I know businesses that straight up throw out cover letters. They get the resume, have someone enter the data on it into a system, get the salary requirement, and from there on out up until you get called in for interview the process is automatic.